# Left join get all data in both table

Tags: sql-server, select, join

I have two tables `Q` and `A`,

records are `A` are

```
QID     UserID     Value
1      100        A
2      100        B
3      100        C
1      101        AA
2      101        BB
3      101        CC
1      102        AAA
2      102        BBB
```

As you can see, there is no record for user `102` for QID `3`. There is this another table `Q`.

```
QID    Value
1      Name
2      Email
3      Site
```

What I want is, for each user, weather they have answered a question or not (that is, weather a entry exits in `A` table or not) I want all questions for all users and their answers. Something like this.

```
QID    QValue     UserID     Value
1      Name       100        A
2      Email      100        B
3      Site       100        C
1      Name       101        AA
2      Email      101        BB
3      Site       101        CC
1      Name       102        AAA
2      Email      102        BBB
```

**What the problem is** one row is missing from the desired output, and that is

```
3      Site       102        NULL
```

Because for user `102` there is no entry in `A` table. I tried `LEFT JOIN`, but obviously it won't give the desired result as all the left table are already there. And `INNER JOIN` doesn't works either.

It is also complete possible for answers table (table `A`) to have data like this

```
QID    QValue     UserID     Value
1      Name       100        A
2      Email      101        BB
3      Site       102        CCC
```

Say, all users just have filled in one record, in this case desired output is something like this

```
QID    QValue     UserID     Value
1      Name       100        A
2      Email      100        NULL
3      Site       100        NULL
1      Name       101        NULL
2      Email      101        BB
3      Site       101        NULL
1      Name       102        NULL
2      Email      102        NULL
3      Email      102        CCC
```

If I do a `LEFT JOIN` on `QID` it doesn't works. Please suggest what should be done.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you mean by "If I do a LEFT JOIN on QID it doesn't works"? How about some ddl and sample data? sqlfiddle.com is a great place to start.

Comment: Look into CROSS JOIN without any condition, you want to CROSS JOIN your Users and your questions and left join with your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
declare @A table(QID int, UserID int, Value varchar(10))
declare @Q table(QID int, Value varchar(10))

insert into @A values (1, 100, 'A')
insert into @A values (2, 100, 'B')
insert into @A values (3, 100, 'C')
insert into @A values (1, 101, 'AA')
insert into @A values (2, 101, 'BB')
insert into @A values (3, 101, 'CC')
insert into @A values (1, 102, 'AAA')
insert into @A values (2, 102, 'BBB')

insert into @Q values (1, 'Name')
insert into @Q values (2, 'Email')
insert into @Q values (3, 'Site')

select 
    U.UserID,
    Q.QID,
    Q.Value as QValue,
    A.Value 
from
    (select distinct UserID from @A) U -- all Users
    cross join @Q Q -- all Questions
    left outer join @A A on A.UserID = U.UserID and A.QID = Q.QID
```

So basically you do a `cross join` between all questions and all users first to get all combinations. Then you take this result and do a `left join` with all the answers. Missing answers will have `NULL` values in the `Value` (the real answer) field.